# direct an object in a 2D game not to collide with obstacles, walls, etc. in java

Tags: java

I am building a pac-man game in plain java(no external library) and my map is like the the original pacman game as in the screenshot attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQLAF.png)
(the squares are made in power-point) and i succeeded to manage that pacman should not to collide with the walls arond the board game but in all the walls in the middle of the board i can't figure out the algorithm that it should only move until the wall exactly (everything i tried makes pacman overlap the wall a bit)
the tiles are created from a 2D array of integers an based on the number the program knows what tile to put there the numbers that represent tiles that pacman is aloud to go are 1, 3, 4.
I have one function that returns a boolean if pacman can move there, it exepts a x and y and the x and y represent the current position + 4 / - 4 (the speed) depends an what key the the player pressed.
her is the punction:

```
//31 is the amount of rows and 28 is the amount of colums
    public static boolean canMove(int x, int y, String direction){
        int speed = 4;
        int tileSize = 16;
        int minX = (tileSize / 2 / 2);
        int maxX = (tileSize * 28) - (tileSize * 2 - (tileSize / 2 / 2));
        int minY = (tileSize / 2 / 2);
        int maxY = tileSize * 31 - (tileSize * 2 - (tileSize / 2 /2));
        int row = (y / tileSize);
        int col = (x / tileSize);
        boolean isInRange = x + (tileSize * 2) <= tileSize * 28 - (x + (tileSize * 2));

        if((x <= minX || x >= maxX) || (y <= minY || y >= maxY)){
            return false;
        }
        if(map[row][col] == 1 || map[row][col] == 3  || map[row][col] == 4 ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

any help will be realy appreciated
Thank you

already written in the question

Comment: Your code is not making use of `direction` at all.  Use it to check the tile next to the tile at `map[row][col]`.  Also you should use enums for your map values and direction values.